# Is it possible to give an application window-control buttons which it currently does not have?

Tags: gnome, window, gimp, maximized, window-control

I don't know how possible this will be as I have programmed a lot before and have often set it so that programs are not able to be resized etc and making it so that it does not have certain window-control buttons (the minimize, maximize, and close buttons).

However, I was wondering, as I also do a lot of work in GIMP I have noticed that even when putting it into single-window mode (as I like it), I am able to resize it a lot by dragging on the edges and corners, but there is no maximize button, only a close and minimize button.
So when I accidentally drag it so that it is not centred on the screen, as it does not like to resize other than being manually dragged, and dragging it to the corners or edges of my screen doesn't resize it to anything, I am forced to just manually drag the edges until it's roughly ok, however this is mostly not accurate and part of it hangs off the screen which is unhelpful as some of the options also go off the screen... 
Anyway, you get the picture, so I was wondering, is there any way of making it so that it does have a maximize button even though it currently does not have one? Is it possible to add window-control buttons to applications which currently do not have them without editing source code (though that would be a last resort option)?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
Flavour: GNOME
GNOME Version: 3.18
```

**Package Information:**

```
gimp:
  Installed: 2.8.14-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2.8.14-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 2.8.14-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: What sort of GIMP do you have? O.o Both my 14.04 and Arch Linux versions have maximize buttons, both using GNOME Shell.

Comment: Will that be ok solution to have a shortcut that binds a script which will "maximize" your current window ? I'm sure it can be done fairly easily and quickly im bash or Python. Not quite sure if it will work well with dual screen though

Comment: @muru: I don't know, I just installed the latest one from the repositories...

Comment: @Serg: No, because GIMP is just an example, my main question is how to add a window-control button generally.

Comment: You have to figure out what's taking that button away from you, and stop it from doing that - and this isn't GIMP, more likely your window manager, so check its settings. An easy answer to get it back might be "don't use Ubuntu", but I guess that one isn't really popular around here :)